# Simplifying system of equations with two variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the system

$$\begin{cases}
x + y = 7 \\
xy = 12
\end{cases}$$

I can find the answer by trial and error method. But is there any another way to find the answer?

Comment: First, this isn't a linear system.  Second, what's wrong with substituting one value into the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y = \frac{12}{x}$ thus we get

$$
x +y \;\; =\;\; x + \frac{12}{x} \;\; = \;\; 7
$$

so $x^2 - 7x + 12 = 0$.  Does the rest seem reasonable now?

Answer (score 4):

Observe that : $(x-y)^2 = (x+y)^2 - 4xy = 7^2 - 4\cdot 12 = 1 \to x-y = ?$, and with $x+y = 7$. Can you ...take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$x(7-x)=12\Rightarrow x^2-7x+12=0\Rightarrow (x-3)(x-4)=0\Rightarrow x=3 \text{ or }x=4$.

Since $x+y=7$ we have $x=3\text{ and }y=4$ or $x=4\text{ and }y=3$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard problem about quadratic equations. I'll explain the solution to the general problem: given two numbers $s$ and $p$, find $x,y$ such that:
$$\begin{cases}x+y=s\\xy=p\end{cases}$$
It is based on the factorisation of the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$. If $x_0, x_1$ are its roots (not necessarily real, nor distinct), we have:
$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_0)(x-x_1)=a\bigl(x^2-(x_0+x_1)x+x_0x_1\bigr) $$
Thus the solutions of the system are simply the roots of the quadratic equation:
$$X^2-sX+p=0. $$